# Unit Testing - Can't Access Method From Repository Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, moq

I'm writing a **Unit Test**, which verifies a specific product is selected with the correct data. Currently, the test is providing the following error:

***System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***

> While debugging through the test, I noticed that my `result` variable is null... I thought I was calling my `SelectProduct` method correctly, but not sure what is wrong.
>
> **Additional question** - Any suggestions on how to better Assert?

```
[TestClass]
    public class ProductRepositoryTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void SelectProduct_selectProduct_productIsSelected()
        {        
            // access ProductRepository
            Mock<IProductRepository> mock = new Mock<IProductRepository>();

            // Arrange - mocked product
            Product product1 = new Product
            {
                ProductId = 1,
                ProductName = "Snicker Bar",
                ProductPrice = .25M,
                ProductCategory = "Candy",
                ProductQuantity = 12
            };

            // Act - select new product using SelectProduct method
            var result = mock.Object.SelectProduct(product1.ProductId);

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(result.ProductId, 1);
            Assert.AreEqual(result.ProductName, "Snicker Bar");
            Assert.AreEqual(result.ProductPrice, .25M);
        }
    }
```

Here is the other code for my Repository layer:

**Interface:**

```
public interface IProductRepository
{
    Product SelectProduct(int productId);
}
```

**Repository Class:**

```
 public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
    {
        public Product SelectProduct(int productId)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your System Under Test in this test? It seems you are testing a mock/fake object, not a real class.

Comment: That is a good question @YacoubMassad... I am trying to test the method in my ProductRepository. Does that help? Please keep in mind that I haven't implemented my SelectProduct method so that I can follow TDD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to test the `ProductRepository` class, but instead your a testing a fake object.

Here is how your test should look like:

```
// Arrange
var sut = new ProductRepository(); //sut means System Under Test
...

// Act - select new product using SelectProduct method
var result = sut.SelectProduct(product1.ProductId);

// Assert
....
```

Fakes (or Mocks) are only used to fake the dependencies of the class under test, not the class itself. So, in this particular test, you don't need to use a mocking framework.

Comment: Thank you so much @YacoubMassad... I'll mark this as the answer once the time frame opens up... What do you think of my Asserts, is that a good way to test that I selected the correct product? Also, I have other classes with Dependency Injection, will I need to use Mock for those?

Comment: Your asserts are OK. One potential improvement is to make the `Product` class implement `IEquatable<Product>` and then your can have a single `Assert.AreEqual` that compares `product1` with `result`.

Comment: If you are testing a class that has dependencies, then you should create fakes/mocks of these dependencies and inject them manually into the SUT constructor.